# how to handle variables in bash for mike yq v4

Tags: kubernetes, yq

How can I use Mike Farah's YQ v4 to update a field that has special characters.

e.g. manipulating below:

```
      containers:
        - name: flyway
          image: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage:60
```

Errors for attempts:

```
$ yq e ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].image=xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage:61" flyway.yaml
Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax

$ yq e ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].image=xx\.dkr\.ecr\.eu-west-1\.amazonaws\.com\/testimage:61" flyway.yaml
Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:53 failing at 1:54.
        unmatched text: "\\"

#########

$ echo $image
xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage:61
$ yq e ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].image=$image" flyway.yaml
Error: Bad expression, please check expression syntax
```

Didnt find any documents explaining any escape characters for special character.

Answer (score 1):

Found this documentation:
https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators

This worked for me:

```
$ echo $image
xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage:61
$ myenv=$image yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image=env(myenv)' flyway.yaml
<<removed contents for brevity >>
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flyway
          image: xx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/testimage:61
```